# Is my headtube unusually long?

Tags: headset, steerer

[image: headtube]

So I was looking to exchange my fork to Suntour one and red that their steerer tubes are just 255mm length, is that too short for my bike? Does anyone even sell forks with longer steerer tubes or is the 255mm standard? And is my headtube unusually long at 215mm?

Also manufacturer calls my headset zero stack:
HEADSET - 1-1/8" Zero Stack Threadless

Comment: Do you plan to replace a rigid fork with a suspension fork? If true, this might be not the best idea, bike frame geometry should specifically support front suspension, otherwise you'll encounter various problem like this one. Usually, longer head tubes correspond to bigger frame size. Different bike types have different head tube length range too.

Comment: There are even longer head tubes out there, I have a frame that uses a 336mm steerer tube. But as far as I can tell, you cannot buy forks with such long steerers off the shelf, you need to get a frame builder to make one for you.

Comment: Lighter fork maybe carbon one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the image, I will assume this is some kind of 61-63CM or XL to XXL trekking/hybrid bike. If true, no, your head tube is not unusually long for the size and type of bike you have.

You also say you want ligher. Replacing what you have with any suspension fork, but especially with a basic one, won't do that.

If you really want to go with a cheap suspension fork, the main way to handle this situation I know of would be one of the RST 300mm steerers, which to my awareness can be transplanted into most or all of their straight 1-1/8" 700 hybrid/trekking/urban type forks. (It's been a while since I've had to mess with this so I don't know the current compatibility rules in their lineup for what can and can't take the 300mm aftermarket steerers they sell; you would need to do that research to be safe.)

Otherwise your off the shelf options would be various rigid forks, which are easy to find in 300mm.

Answer (score 2):

That is definitely one longggggg head tube.

You have a few options:

- A high rise stem.
- As mentioned by Matt in the comments, buying riser handlebars is also a solution.
- A steerer tube extension.

Any of these options can be used together to create the handlebar rise you need to replicate your current body position. You may get away with only needing one modification if you’re willing to lower the bars compared to your current setup.

Comment: I was planning to get lighter fork for the bike. I guess my position is ok'ish a bit upright maybe.

Comment: @MT247 Do you really need to get a lighter fork? It looks like you currently have a rigid steel fork. A suspension fork will be even heavier than the one you have right now.

Comment: Yeah I want lighter fork, this is not that good and really heavy

Comment: @MT247 I don’t believe Suntour makes carbon rigid forks, only suspension forks.

Comment: Riser bars will give from 10mm- 40mm or possibly more height, enough to replace the stack of spacers.